# How to automatically create a python re pattern from a file name?

Tags: python, regex

As an input, I have a filename (e.g. "bla150420.txt") containing a date in a specific format. I need to look into a given folder (containing many files) and find the latest version of my file. (And I have to do it automatically - many times for different files in different folders.)
Example directory (dirname):

- ...
- bla150420.txt
- bla150425.txt
- bla150510.txt

Example output:

- bla150510.txt

How can I do so? My original approach was to parse a date out of the file name, substitute the date with RE pattern and to search this pattern in the list of all filenames. This doesn't seem to work. Any idea? Or different approach?

```
    def get_date(file_name):
        DATE_RE = re.compile('([0-9]{6})')    #EDITED - TYPO
        try:
            match = DATE_RE.search(fname).group()
        except AttributeError:
            sys.stderr.write('ERROR! No date matches string!\n\t' + match)
        else:
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(match, '%Y%m%d')
            return match, date

    date_string, current_date = get_date(fname)
    # fname is a given file name (e.g. bla150420.txt)

    pattern1 = re.compile(re.sub(date_string, '(.*)', fname))
    # pattern1 returns value 'kds_docs-(.*).zip'

    pattern2 = re.compile('kds_docs-(.*).zip')

    if os.path.isdir(dirname):
        matching_files = [x for x in os.listdir(dirname) 
                          if pattern1.search(x)]
```

It is a wonder to me, my program works with pattern2, but not with pattern1. If I print those two (using .pattern), it looks like the same result, if I compare it with '==' it returns False. I have no idea whether it is because of encoding/whitespace/something else nor how to find the difference. Could you please help?

Comment: Do you actually *need* regex for this? It seems like you just want `max(filenames, key=lambda filename: datetime.datetime.strptime(filename[3:-4], '%Y%m%d'))` (i.e. *"convert everything between `bla` and `.txt` into a date and give me whichever has the largest"*).

Comment: Is it a typo? Your file name example is `bla150420.txt` (note **6** digits), when your regex requires **8** (`'([0-9]{8})'`)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it looks like the current desire is to find all files that match the provided file name (except that the date should be ignored). If provided `bla150420.txt`, the resulting regex should match anything starting with `bla` and ending with `.txt`

Comment: @CodeJockey but they want to get the one with the most recent date, which makes no sense if some of them don't have the date

Comment: @SergeBallesta - it would seem that protion of the actual algorithm is working, or there would have been a different symptom - I'd guess that was a copy error, but if it is in the actual code, there are some verrrry strange things happening

Comment: @jonrsharpe -- the presented solution looks valid enough for what it's coded to do, except as pointed out by Serge -- I believe the current solution is not at the point of sorting and finding the most recent - it's at the point of matching all the files with e.g. `bla` at the beginning and `.txt` at the end. I think OP is currently asking why she can't produce the pattern correctly in an automated fashion (`pattern1` assignment) when the manually created regex (`pattern2` assignment) does work. The expressions appear visually identical when printed

Comment: @CodeJockey then this is **Unclear what you're asking**, I will wait to see what (if anything) else the OP adds.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sure - I could go with that. It's certainly confusing - badly asked. However, I think the last paragraph combined with the fact that there is no sorting or selecting of a "latest" file being done in the posted code leaves little room for another interpretation after critical analysis.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: 6/8 digits was a typo, sorry, (there are few different date formats as well, I have copied a wrong line).

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I think I do need a redex - the filename string can be whatever and it can have a various extensions - the only input is an existing file containing a date in some specified format and a path to a directory, where you can find various versions of this file and possibly some other files as well.

Sorry if I am being unclear. My question is exactly what you understood. Why the concept of creating a pattern in an automated way doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're merely having issues with producing a *working regex* in an *automated fashion.*

Serge pointed out that your code as presented should get tripped up by the fact that your dates seem to have 6 digits instead of 8, but that first regex requires 8 digits - correct or explain that if it's more than a typo.

I suppose you're looking to verify that any string of digits actually is a date, but this seems unnecessary, since a filename could have a string of digits which parses as a date,  but isn't the date you're looking for - not ideal. Let me know if it MUST be a date.

I'm unfamiliar with the intricacies of Python, but I would suggest simplifying your regex production by not even using your function:

```
pattern1 = re.compile(re.sub('([0-9]{6})', '(.*)', fname))
```

Just make the replacement directly. I would say it would probably be safer to go a little further like so:

```
pattern1 = re.compile(re.sub('([0-9]{6})', '(\d{6})', fname))
```

...and if there are any other possible restrictions, you could limit 6 digit matches further. For instance, the 6 digit string might always be at the end of the file name, just before the extension:

```
pattern1 = re.compile(re.sub('([0-9]{6})(?=\..*$)', '(\d{6})', fname))
# should turn 'kds_docs-120501-151023.zip' into 'kds_docs-150510-(\d{6}).zip'
```